# Select part of duration that occurs in specific hour of day

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server, I have a table of processes with a starttime and an endtime, from which I can calculate a duration using DATEDIFF.

```
Name        StartTime           EndTime
------------------------------------------------
process1    2016-10-10 11:10    2016-10-10 11:20
process2    2016-10-10 11:40    2016-10-10 12:30
```

How can I select the timespan of the process duration that occured in specific hours of the day (11 and 12) in seconds?

So process1 would be 10 minutes in hour 11.
process2 would be 20 minutes in hour 11, 30 minutes in hour 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample that will generate hourly records for each source record. It uses a recursive CTE to move from the StartTime of each record through the EndTime. It may need some slight modifications to make it work in your case, but hopefully you can get the idea of how this method works.

Note that, as shown in the sample below, this will work properly even if the time span crosses a date boundary.

```
--==================================================================================
-- Do some quick setup to get a temporary table populated with data to use:
--==================================================================================
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProcessHistory', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ProcessHistory;
CREATE TABLE #ProcessHistory (
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    StartTime DATETIME,
    EndTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #ProcessHistory
VALUES  ('process1', '2016-10-10 11:10', '2016-10-10 11:20'),
        ('process2', '2016-10-10 11:40', '2016-10-10 12:30'),
        ('process3', '2016-10-10 22:21', '2016-10-11 02:36');

--==================================================================================
-- Use a recursive CTE to generate hourly data for each record:
--==================================================================================
WITH HourlyData AS (
    -- Anchor:
    SELECT
        ph.Name [ProcessName],
        ph.StartTime [StartTime],
        ph.EndTime [EndTime],
        -- Get the current hour with date:
        DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, ph.StartTime), ph.StartTime) [CurrentHour],
        -- Calculate the next hour for use later:
        DATEADD(MINUTE, 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, ph.StartTime), ph.StartTime) [NextHour],
        -- Determine how many minutes the process was active this hour:
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ph.StartTime, ph.EndTime) > 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, ph.StartTime)
                THEN 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, ph.StartTime)
            ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ph.StartTime, ph.EndTime)
        END [Minutes]
    FROM #ProcessHistory ph

    UNION ALL

    -- Recurse:
    SELECT
        hd.ProcessName,
        hd.StartTime,
        hd.EndTime,
        hd.NextHour [CurrentHour],
        DATEADD(HOUR, 1, hd.NextHour) [NextHour],
        -- Determine how many minutes the process was active this hour:
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, hd.NextHour, hd.EndTime) < 60
                THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, hd.NextHour, hd.EndTime)
            ELSE 60
        END
    FROM HourlyData hd
    WHERE hd.NextHour < hd.EndTime
)
SELECT
    hd.ProcessName,
    hd.CurrentHour [HourWithDate],
    CONVERT(DATE, hd.CurrentHour) [Date],
    DATEPART(HOUR, hd.CurrentHour) [Hour],
    hd.Minutes
FROM HourlyData hd
ORDER BY
    hd.ProcessName,
    hd.CurrentHour;
```

The output from the above sample would look like this:

```
ProcessName HourWithDate            Date        Hour    Minutes
process1    2016-10-10 11:00:00.000 2016-10-10  11      10
process2    2016-10-10 11:00:00.000 2016-10-10  11      20
process2    2016-10-10 12:00:00.000 2016-10-10  12      30
process3    2016-10-10 22:00:00.000 2016-10-10  22      39
process3    2016-10-10 23:00:00.000 2016-10-10  23      60
process3    2016-10-11 00:00:00.000 2016-10-11  0       60
process3    2016-10-11 01:00:00.000 2016-10-11  1       60
process3    2016-10-11 02:00:00.000 2016-10-11  2       36
```

Comment: Thanks @Soukai this appears to do the trick, or at least point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick, but it's pretty ugly.  Maybe someone can do it more elegantly?

```
SELECT 
   case 
     when HOUR(starttime) < 11 AND HOUR(endtime) = 11  then minute(endtime)
     when HOUR(starttime) < 11 AND HOUR(endtime) > 11  then 60
     when HOUR(starttime) = 11 AND HOUR(endtime) = 11  then minute(endtime) - minute(starttime)
     when HOUR(starttime) = 11 AND HOUR(endtime) > 11  then 60 - minute(starttime)
     else 0
   end AS ProcessTimeHour_11,
    case 
     when HOUR(starttime) < 12 AND HOUR(endtime) = 12  then minute(endtime)
     when HOUR(starttime) < 12 AND HOUR(endtime) > 12  then 60
     when HOUR(starttime) = 12 AND HOUR(endtime) = 12  then minute(endtime) - minute(starttime)
     when HOUR(starttime) = 12 AND HOUR(endtime) > 12  then 60 - minute(starttime)
     else 0
   end AS ProcessTimeHour_12
from StuffAndThings
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2016-10-10 11:10','2016-10-10 12:20'),'2011-01-01 00:00:00.000') AS TIME)
as timeDifference
```

---

With timeDifference -

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartTime,EndTime),'2011-01-01 00:00:00.000') AS TIME)
as timeDifference 
from #YourTableName
```

---

With Days and TimeDiffernece

```
    declare @start_time as varchar(150);
    declare @end_time as varchar(150);
    set @start_time='2016-10-10 10:10';
    set @end_time='2016-10-12 12:10'

    SELECT datediff(day,@start_time,@end_time) as dayDifference,
CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_time,@end_time),'2011-01-01 00:00:00') AS TIME(0))
 as timeDifference
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle general cases, you could try something like

```
    --drop table #processes 
CREATE TABLE #processes 
    (
    name  varchar(50),
    StartTime  Datetime,
    EndTime  DateTime
    );

    insert #processes VALUES('proc1','20161010 11:10','20161010 11:20');
    insert #processes VALUES('proc2','20161010 11:40','20161010 12:20');
    insert #processes VALUES('proc3','20161010 10:40','20161010 12:20');

;WITH HRS   AS  (SELECT 0 HR 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT HR + 1 FROM HRS WHERE HR < 23),
    MINS    AS  (SELECT 0 MN 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT MN + 1 FROM MINS WHERE MN < 59),
    TIMES   AS  (SELECT HR,MN FROM HRS CROSS JOIN MINS)
    SELECT name,starttime,endtime,Count(0) AS mins FROM #processes
                    JOIN TIMES 
                            ON (HR > datepart(hh,Starttime) 
                                OR HR = datepart(hh,Starttime)   AND MN >= datepart(n,STARTtIME))
                                AND 
                                (HR < datepart(hh, EndTime) 
                                OR HR = datepart(hh, EndTime)  AND MN < datepart(n,EndTime))

                    WHERE HR = 11 --hour is 11

        GROUP BY name,
                    starttime,
                    endtime                     



    drop table #processes;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp (Name varchar(5), starttime datetime, EndTime datetime)

insert into #temp values(1,'2016-10-10 11:10','2016-10-10 11:20' )
insert into #temp values(2,'2016-10-10 11:40','2016-10-10 12:30' )
insert into #temp values(2,'2016-10-10 10:40','2016-10-10 11:30' )
insert into #temp values(2,'2016-10-10 10:40','2016-10-10 12:30' )  


    DECLARE @firstTime time ,@secondTime time
    set @firstTime ='11:00'
    set @secondTime ='12:00'

    select
     CASE WHEN CONVERT(time(0), starttime) < @firstTime AND CONVERT(time(0), EndTime) > @secondTime  THEN  DATEDIFF(ss,@firstTime,@secondTime)
          WHEN CONVERT(time(0), EndTime) > @secondTime THEN DATEDIFF(ss,CONVERT(time(0), starttime),@secondTime)
          WHEN CONVERT(time(0), starttime) < @firstTime THEN DATEDIFF(ss,CONVERT(time(0), EndTime),@secondTime)
         ELSE DATEDIFF(ss,starttime,EndTime) 
     END
    from #temp
```